# Arabic text over an textPath in d3.js svg gets flipped in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, svg, arabic-support

I'm trying to implement arabic texts over textpath for an d3 visualization.
I need text to be curved over an arc.

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GogdR.png)

I have tried different options like dir=rtl , xml:lang="fa and even reversing the text which found no success.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>
    Curved Text in SVG
  </title>
  <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    svg {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    circle {
      fill: blue;
    }
    
    path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: white;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
    
    text {
      font-family: cursive;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-anchor: middle;
    }
    
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>!مرحبا بالعالم</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var width = 300,
      height = 400,
      radius = 150;
    // insert the main SVG element
    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr({
        height: height,
        width: width,
        id: 'mainSVG',
        dir: 'rtl'
      });
    // get the width of the SVG
    var width = document.getElementById('mainSVG').getBoundingClientRect().width;
    // path data generation depends on width and radius we've chosen
    function getPathData() {
      // adjust the radius a little so our text's baseline isn't sitting directly on the circle
      var r = radius * 0.95;
      var startX = width / 2 - r;
      return 'm' + startX + ',' + (height / 2) + ' ' +
        'a' + r + ',' + r + ' 0 0 0 ' + (2 * r) + ',0';
    }
    // add our path definition for the curved textPath to follow
    svg.append('defs')
      .append('path')
      .attr({
        d: getPathData,
        id: 'curvedTextPath'
      });
    // add our circle element centered within the svg
    svg.append('circle')
      .attr({
        cx: width / 2,
        cy: height / 2,
        r: radius,
        id: 'mainCircle'
      });
    // add our path element in the main SVG so we can see it for reference
    svg.append('path')
      .attr({
        d: getPathData,
        id: 'visiblePath'
      });


    // add our text with embedded textPath and link the latter to the defined #curvedTextPath
    svg.append('text')
      .append('textPath')
      .attr({
        startOffset: '50%',
        'xlink:href': '#curvedTextPath',
        'method': 'stretch '
      })
      .text('!مرحبا بالعال');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Somebody please put light how to achieve the expected output. If not possible directly, what are the possible workarouds to achieve the same.

Comment: Looks like a browser bug. Firefox's rendering is not the same as your raster image for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the info. You are right it works fine in Firefox. Is there any possible solution to fix it for chrome. Coz most of the target users expected use it.

Comment: Chrome is open source. Download the code and fix it or pay someone to do so on your behalf.

Comment: That's a known and old bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=374526 You can "star" the issue so that it gets an higher priority than what it currently has, but it seems it's not an easy case.